# How to find numbers from word in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I would ask you help me to solve this problem . How i can find numbers from this word?
Problem is that:  S1e2n3t4e5n6c7e
Result should be  : 1234567
Thanks for attention...

Comment: Have you tried something so far ??? If so share with us ...

Answer (score -2):

You can do :

```
"S1e2n3t4e5n6c7e".replaceAll("[^0-9]+", "");
```

Comment: You should let OP to provide what he has done so far.. Giving an answer right away not let people to think and come up with a solution...

Comment: @CédricL. Please OP has not even tried something.